# When clicking on a link inside the accordion menu, how can I keep the accordion menu open once the page is refreshed with new html content?

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions, w3c

Navigation Menu -- menu needs to stay open when page is refreshed by clicking on another link

```
ul class="menu">
                    <li class="item1"><a href="#">Hardware</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="subitem1"><a href="receipt-printer.html">Receipt Printer</a></li>
                            <li class="subitem2"><a href="barcode-scanner.html">Barcode <span class="item-move2">Scanner</span> </a></li>
                            <li class="subitem3"><a href="card-swipes.html">Card Swipes</a></li>
                            <li class="subitem4"><a href="weighscales.html">Weighscales</a></li>
                            <li class="subitem5"><a href="touchscreens.html">Touchscreens</a></li>
                            <li class="subitem6"><a href="label-printer.html">Label Printer</a></li>
                            <li class="subitem7"><a href="customer-display.html">Customer <span class="item-move2"> Display</span></a></li>
                            <li class="subitem8"><a href="wap.html">WAP</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="item2"><a href="#">Software</a>
                        <ul>
                           <li class="subitem1"><a href="step1/install-ootpik.html">Installing ootpik</a></li>
                            <li class="subitem2"><a href="step1/pref-security.html">Preferences &amp; <span class="item-move2">Security</span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

end of menu
Script to operate the accordion menu

```
<!--initiate accordion-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

        var menu_ul = $('.menu > li > ul'),
               menu_a  = $('.menu > li > a');

             menu_ul.hide();

        menu_a.click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if(!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
                menu_a.removeClass('active');
                menu_ul.filter(':visible').slideUp('normal');
                $(this).addClass('active').next().stop(true,true).slideDown('normal');
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('active');
                $(this).next().stop(true,true).slideUp('normal');
            }

        });

    });
</script>
```

end of script

website to view the accordion now:
http://www.ootpik.info/lauren/ootpik5/receipt-printer.html

Comment: You should really try to reduce this to just what is required to explain and demonstrate the issue/question.  That is a ton of code.  You should also explain the issue/question in detail within the body of your question, not just in the title of the question.

Comment: code changed....I can get it to stay open, but i dosen't refresh properly. It will lock the accordion

Comment: i think the question is how to make our javascript transcend a http request/response… No i'm just kidding, i don't understand the question either. If you have some back-end you could configure your javascript through sessions.

Comment: changed the question, I'm pretty sure I'm just over thinking this, but could someone give me some insight please

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try another menu selector based on your current url (because when your page refreshes you can't get menu item clicked before). It could be something like this (for receipt-printer.html page):

```
$('.menu > li > ul:not(:has(li > a[href="receipt-printer.html"]))')
```

It's hard coded but I think it could work for you.
The value of current page you can get from `window.location.pathname`. For example like this:

```
var url = window.location.pathname.split('/')[3] //because on your site you have relative url lauren/ootpik5/receipt-printer.html
```

But it also hard coded and I'm not sure that it will work for any urls on your site.

So full example of algorithm could be:

```
var splittedUrl = window.location.pathname.split('/');
var href = splittedUrl[splittedUrl.length - 1];
var menu_ul = $('.menu > li > ul:not(:has(li > a[href="' + href + '"]))');
munu_ul.hide();
```

Comment: I think i'm going to use a different menu selector, this just hides my navigation completely off the page, but thanks

Comment: I found a way while using this accordion menu system. You have to dynamically grab all the page content using javascript or ajax, whatever you want to use. This also runs into another problem of not being able to use the back or forward buttons. So from then you need to  use the hashchange to all the forward and back buttons to be used

Comment: If you want to use ajax and maintain back and forward buttons functionality take a look at history API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history . It doesn't work in all browsers (http://caniuse.com/#search=history), but some polyfills exist: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills